# SlimFramework - Access Route Variables Via Custom Function

Tags: php, slim

I have the following route I'm setting.

```
$app->post(
    '/:device/admin/(/)',
    'get_user',
    $validate_user(
        array(
            'Admin',
            'Manager'
        ),'
        templates'
    ),'
    render_bronzeservice'
)->conditions(
    array('device'=>'(tablet|desktop|mobile)')
);
```

I want to be able to pass the route variable **:device** to the function **$validate_user**

How do I do this?

For the function `render_bronzeservice`, it simply expects a parameter for the device, but this does not work for custom functions or I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I found a workaround for now, its ugly but it will work.  Since I get the user data in the function before it, I do the check there for the parameter.

Oddly for some reason it does not send it as a string? But sends it as a route object to the first function.

So my get_user function looks like this.

```
function get_user($route){
    global $user;
    global $device;

    //If there is any route device info...
    if(isset($route->getParams()['device'])){
        $device = $route->getParams()['device'];//set the device sent from the route.
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) && !empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        //Do database lookup on userID and set to global $user
        //echo "User Found";
        $user = User::find(array('id' => $_SESSION['userid']));//sets the user super global variable from the database accordingly.
    }else{
        //echo "User Not Found<br/>";
    }
}
```

By using a global variable to keep track of the device, I can then read it in the next function in line $validate_user by declaring global in that function.

It's a weird workaround, but working for now.